# Visual Studio 2013 c++ function syntax error

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS 2013, for some reason in a C++ console application a simple function declaration will not work.  What is going on?

[image: odd error]

I have #include iostream and the code is inside the int main () {...} body.

-TSR

UPDATE:

Here is the full program

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the whole code (including main)

Comment: You can't define functions inside other functions.

Comment: Please convert your imagines to actual text, images are subject to link rot which would make this question useless to future visitors. You can indicate with comments where the errors occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the comment in my program. You should write functions outside of the main method.

[image: Look at the comment in my program]

```
/* Wrong code
-----------------------------------------
*/
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 int printmessage ()
 {
 }
}


/* Correct code
----------------------------------------
*/
#include <iostream>

int printmessage ()
{
}

int main()
{    
}
```

Comment: Since the bulk of your content is an image you should add more content since images are subject to link rot which would make this answer much less useful.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to define a function within another function, although you are allowed to declare one. So something like this is allowed:

```
int main()
{
    void func1() ; // function declaration but not definition.
}

void func1()
{
  //...    
}
```

but this is probably what makes more sense for you:

```
int printmessage()
{
    //...
}

int main()
{
}
```

Function definitions are only allowed in the namespace or class scope, from the draft C++ standard section `8.4` *Function definitions* paragraph *2* says:

> [...]A function shall be defined only in namespace or class scope.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a function definition inside the main loop. You can either use function prototyping before the main(int argc, char** argv) or define the function before the main.

```
// Either define your function here
void Foo() { }

// Or use this prototyping
void Bar();

int main ()
{
    // Call your function here
    Foo();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void Bar() { }
```

Hope this helps.

For the declaration of function inside another function, it is just the backward compatibility with C programming. I doubt if anyone ever use this anymore. Plus, this is C++ not C